# C# / VB.Net Task vs Thread vs BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker, task

I have "Googled" but still confused with Task, Thread, and Background Worker.....

1. Is "Task is a high level API that running on current thread" correct ?
2. If 1 is correct, why I need to use invoke to change the UI inside the task at same thread ?
3. Backgroundworker only got lowest priority in the application ? So the performance of backgroundworker is lower than task and thread ? Right ?
4. Finally, in my application I need to get a string from server using "HttpWebRequest", after that parse the string and update the UI. 
   If I use "HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse" to wait for the async result and trigger an complete event to update the UI, I need to use invoke method to call the UI thread control, but can I use background  worker instead of ? I can just simply change the UI in "RunWorkerCompleted" event, are there any disadvantage ?

Sorry for my pool English and thanks for help...!

Comment: Tasks use the threadPool behind the scenes, they aren't restricted to the current thread that invokes them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) No, a Task is by default run on a thread pool thread. You can provide another scheduler which can run tasks differently, though.

3) There is no difference in priority by default. `BackgroundWorker` also runs on a thread pool thread.

4) Using [`TaskFactory.FromAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321311.aspx) is a rather simple way to handle asynchronous web requests:

```
Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)
    .ContinueWith(
        t =>
        {
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)t.Result)
            {
                // Do your work
            }
        },
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    );
```

Using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` ensures that the callback in `ContinueWith` is invoked on the current thread. So, if the task is created on the UI thread, the response will be retrieved in the background and then processed on the UI thread.